# how to write nginx rewrite rule to direct to another server that work on python

Tags: nginx, php, proxy, reverse-proxy, python

I have the following scenario

1. I have a domain name that is connected to **machine X** which has Nginx and PHP
2. I have **multiple machines 1 to n** who are not exposed public and only accessed by VPN connection
3. **machine X** is the only machine that can be accessed by the public and it is working as a reverse proxy for other **machines 1 to n**
4. I have added multiple rewrite rules in Nginx for example :

```
 location ^~ /machine1/
 {
  rewrite /machine1/(.*) /machine1/$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://web-ha;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
  proxy_redirect off;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
 }
```

This is an example of a rewrite rule that works, but now I want to make it a new rewrite rule for **machineY** that has a different URL and works in python, not PHP, I have tried to use the same format but it keeps giving me **404 not found**

**machineY** has the following iP **171.1.0.117**

I want the user to write **https://www.example.com/machineY** and this URL directed to **171.1.0.117**

Hope I was able to explain my case and please if anyone can help

Comment: `proxy_pass https://171.1.0.117`; would redirect the request to the target 171...

Comment: @djdomi I did it, but it does not work, I do not know if there is because nginx is not suitable to show python website, or if there is another reason

Comment: Does not work is not an acceptable response. Are you admin or end user? For me it sounds like the last one :-) Back to topic, logs logs log... and not only one part of the configuration

Comment: @djdomi it still gives me "HTTP ERROR 404"

Comment: @djdomi I think the problem in this line :   rewrite /machine1/(.*) /machine1/$1 break;
 because it should search for a folder called machine1 but in my case, there is no machine1 folder in www folder to use it because it is a python application and not deployed on PHP www folder